# Restrict the user to submit a form once in a day using Jquery or J.S or php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

i have a form and i want one users submit it **once a day**.  if user submitted the from more then one time in a day the message will show sorry you already done!

Comment: You can only implement secure restrictions on the server.

Comment: but i want it in **client-side** @SLaks

Comment: Not a guru but I guess the best you can do client-side is store some cookie ... but that is not trustable

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We are a community of volunteers offering aid to programmers stuck on a particular task. We are **not** a service to write free code for you. Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @AliHassan: Then you won't have any security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this like this however when the user changes page, the data will be gone. this is something that javascript/jquery should not handle:

make a hidden input,
when submit is pressed, have a submit function:

```
<form id=theForm>
<input type=hidden name=last id=last></input>
<input type=button onclick="submitFunction()"></input>
</form>
```

then have a script

```
<script> 
submitFunction = function() {
  var ONE_DAY = 60 * 60 * 1000 * 24; /* ms */
  var lastTime = document.getElementById('last').value;
  document.getElementById('last').value = new Date();
  if (lastTime == "" || !lastTime)
  {
    document.getElementById('last').value = new Date();
    document.getElementById('theForm').submit();
  }
  else if (((new Date()) - lastTime ) < ONE_DAY)
  {
    alert('you must wait one day');
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById('theForm').submit();
  }

}
</script>
```

To solve this problem properly i suggest using PHP with a database recording when the user last submit the form. This way that data will be kept persistently.

To do this with PHP: 
first create a database;
for this example i will call it test database and table will be called lastcheck.
in the form table have one column : last_time set as a timestamp;
then just

```
<?php 
    $last = "";
    $servername = "xxx";
    $username = "xxx";
    $password = "xxx";
    $dbname = "test";

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("Select last_time from test.lastcheck order by last_time asc limit 1"); 
        $stmt->execute();

        // set the resulting array to associative
        $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
        foreach($stmt->fetchAll() as $k=>$v) { 
            $last = $v;
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        $conn = null;
    }
    $conn = null;


   echo '<form id=theForm>
         <input type=hidden value="'.$last.'" name=last id=last></input>
         <input type=button onclick="submitFunction()"></input>
         </form>';
?>
<script> 
submitFunction = function() {
  var ONE_DAY = 60 * 60 * 1000 * 24; /* ms */
  var lastTime = document.getElementById('last').value;
  document.getElementById('last').value = new Date();
  if (lastTime == "" || !lastTime)
  {
    document.getElementById('last').value = new Date();
    document.getElementById('theForm').submit();
  }
  else if (((new Date()) - lastTime ) < ONE_DAY)
  {
    alert('you must wait one day');
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById('theForm').submit();
  }

}
</script>
```

Basically all thats left now is a method for your form.  should have an action that leads to a new php page that saves a new date to the database and does whatever code you want done when the form is submit, or you could just redirect to the previous page after saving a new date to the database, etc.

Comment: if you can do this with **php** show me the **code** in php

Comment: done. this is written fast, but im sure you can understand the logic im trying to use. basically all thats left is a method for your form. <form id=theForm> should have an action that leads to a php page that saves a new date to the database and does whatever code you want done when the form is submit, or you could just redirect to the previous page after saving a new date to the database. Please accept my answer if this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot check if a user submitted a form using **ONLY** JS or jQuery because they are client based languages...
You need to do that from server-side.
For example you could use PHP and/or a database, or cookies to store when someone submitted then check if he submitted between a day.

Comment: ok if you have a solution in php  then **help me**